# Detecting if Back Button Pressed Issue - GLKViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, glkit

I am trying to detect when the user pressed the back button in a GLKViewController. The view controller is presented via a storyboard from the root view controller (which is a menu).

The problem is that I cannot detect when the back button is pressed (so I can free up memory).

I have tried :

```
if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
    // Do your stuff here
    NSLog(@"Dismissed");
}
```

And

```
if (self.isBeingDismissed) {
    // Do your stuff here
    NSLog(@"Dismissed");
}
```

Neither of which fires. Can anyone suggest why ?

Comment: `viewWillDisappear:` ?

Comment: I don't want it to fire when the user moves forward to the next view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make your own action to BackButton:

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(action:)];

-(void) action:(id)sender {

 //do something here

 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```